# SQL query returning duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a SQL statement as a materialized view and later join the table with a much larger table. I am experiencing issues with violating a duplicate constraint on item/location combo in the larger table. Here is my materialized view query:

```
SELECT /*+ materialize */ CAN.CNCL_CNT, CAN.ITEM, CAN.LOCATION,
      CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE, OL.CANCEL_ID
FROM ORDLOC OL,
     (SELECT COUNT(CANCEL_DATE) AS CNCL_CNT, ITEM, LOCATION, 
             MAX(CANCEL_DATE) AS LAST_CNCL_DTE
      FROM ORDLOC
      WHERE CANCEL_DATE between  (to_date(20160123,'yyyymmdd') -60) and to_date(20160123,'yyyymmdd') 
        AND CANCEL_DATE IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY ITEM, LOCATION) CAN  
WHERE CAN.ITEM = OL.ITEM 
AND CAN.LOCATION = OL.LOCATION
AND CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE = OL.CANCEL_DATE
GROUP BY CAN.CNCL_CNT, CAN.ITEM, CAN.LOCATION, CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE, OL.CANCEL_ID
```

Now when I run the nested query alone, I have few hundred rows less, and item/location combos are all unique, however when running the entire query there will be a few hundred more rows returned with duplicate item/locations.

Comment: ITEM and LOCATION will be unique inside the CAN subquery, but what about in the ORDLOC table/view? Also, just because you use the materialize hint does not make it a "materialized view", which is a very different thing in Oracle. Also, the materialize hint is undocumented and therefore shouldn't be used in production code unless you're prepared for bugs (which I've seen with this hint) and functionality to change unexpected across different versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Was using the materialized hint, to materialize the temporary table. Not sure if it has any effectiveness, as I believe I tried it without the hint to the same effect.

Comment: As for the ordloc table, it doesn't hold unique item/location, but holds a unique "order no", ideally I'd like to only take in the latest cancel date, only.

Comment: It's just semantics, but you're using the hint to materialize the *query* into a temporary table. While there are reasons to need to do something like that (usually because you're referring to the same set of data multiple times + it's faster to fetch the data once + store it), in your case, it's not necessary + may be slowing things down. Please update your question to include sample input + output data showing your issue. (Btw, [Materialized views](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views), which you mentioned in your original question, are something completely different!).

Comment: So, you're finding the latest cancel date for each item/location. What do you need to display from the ORDLOC table? The latest CANCEL_ID? Or do you need to display all corresponding CANCEL_IDs? Because if it's the latter, you can't expect the results to be unique against item+location.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I needed the latest CANCEL_DATE and who canceled that order, ie. CANCEL_ID, as well as a cancel count. I guess my worry was that I had to use a nested query to correctly display the latest CANCEL_ID, I have also tried to include CANCEL_ID in the nested query and just run that, but if there were more than one CANCEL_ID that performed a cancel, it will show both:

Comment: `code`      SELECT /*+ materialize */ COUNT(CANCEL_DATE) AS     CNCL_CNT, ITEM, LOCATION, CANCEL_ID, 
             MAX(CANCEL_DATE) AS LAST_CNCL_DTE
      FROM ORDLOC
      WHERE CANCEL_DATE between (TO_DATE(20160123,'yyyymmdd') -60) and TO_DATE(20160123,'yyyymmdd') 
      GROUP BY ITEM, LOCATION, CANCEL_ID `code` this was what I tried to do without luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use a function, max for CANCEL_ID to eliminate duplicate ITEM/LOCATION. As there is a rare scenario that I have the same ITEM, LOCATION, LAST_CNCL_DATE, but by two different CANCEL_IDs. Here was the code I used.

```
SELECT CAN.CNCL_CNT, CAN.ITEM, CAN.LOCATION,
 CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE, MAX (OL.CANCEL_ID) AS CANCEL_ID
FROM ORDLOC OL,
     (SELECT COUNT(CANCEL_DATE) AS CNCL_CNT, ITEM, LOCATION, 
     MAX(CANCEL_DATE) AS LAST_CNCL_DTE
     FROM ORDLOC
     WHERE CANCEL_DATE BETWEEN (TO_DATE(20160123,'yyyymmdd') -60) AND TO_DATE(20160123,'yyyymmdd') 
     GROUP BY ITEM, LOCATION) CAN  
WHERE CAN.ITEM = OL.ITEM 
AND CAN.LOCATION = OL.LOCATION
AND CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE = OL.CANCEL_DATE
GROUP BY CAN.CNCL_CNT, CAN.ITEM, CAN.LOCATION, CAN.LAST_CNCL_DTE
```